# SQL Server- Get Date 6 months in past

Tags: sql-server

Hey how would I get data for a date column that's older than 6 months?

select * from myTable where dateColumn >

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use DATEDIFF function.

Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(MM, dateColumn, GETDATE()) > 6
```

Comment: DATEDIFF exists exactly for this.

Comment: **Note** that this `DATEDIFF` will do a row-wise function on *every* row, resulting in a full table scan even if you have an index on `dateColumn`.  By comparing to `dateColumn` to `DATEADD(mm, -6, GETDATE())`, you can take advantage of any index you might have and generally see better performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE DATEDIFF(day, NOW(), dateColumn) > 180
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from table
where
date_column >= 
DATEADD(m, -6, convert(date, convert(varchar(6), getdate(),112) + '01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
select * from myTable where dateColumn > DATEADD(mm,GETDATE(),-6)
```

This way you arent applying a function on the lookup column, which in some cases can result in performance issues

Comment: In MS SQL Server, the 2nd and 3rd parameters are reversed `DATEADD(mm, -6, GETDATE())`.  Not sure if this is the valid syntax for another DB

Answer (score 0):

Dateadd is very simple to use. 
the first parameter is the interval, m means month, d means day ect. the second parameter is the increment, and the last one is obviously the date

```
select dateadd(m,6,getdate())
```

more info here
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp

Once you understand dateadd then you can simply use it in where clause as such

```
Select * from Table1 where date1 >= dateadd(m,6,date1)
```