# Get the name of the month 3 months ago

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to run SQL Server code on the 1st of the month that will generate these results:

```
CurrMonth   CurrYear   QtStrtMonth   
June          2018      April
```

I can get the first 2 columns like this:

```
select DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(GETDATE()), 0) -1) as CurrMonth ,datepart(yyyy,(getdate()) ) as CurrYear
```

But this:

```
DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, MONTH(GETDATE()), 0) -4) as QtStrtMonth,
```

does not give me the 3rd column.
Any ideas how I can easily get the NAME of a month "3 months ago"
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server- Get Date 6 months in past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771952/sql-server-get-date-6-months-in-past)

Answer (score 5):

I would simply use:

```
select datename(month, dateadd(month, -4, getdate()))
```

If you need the date of the month that starts the quarter:

```
select datename(month, dateadd(quarter, datediff(quarter, 0, getdate()), 0))
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be super simple, but I couldn't come up with the correct syntax.

Comment: @SheriAnderson Your other two can be simplified as well: `SELECT datename(month,getdate()), year(getdate())`